# Graphs not populating FactoShiny Interface with error

Tags: r, rstudio, correspondence-analysis

I'm trying to run a correspondence analysis using the Factoshiny interface from RStudio. When the interface opens I get this error underneath the Graphs section: "Error: there is no package called ‘systemfonts’". I tried to install.packages("systemfonts") in RStudio and open it but it continues to give me the error. All of the analysis shows up in Values, Summary of Dataset and Data. When I click to download the file as a jpg, png, or pdf the chart populates in the download but not in the interface. Any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install system fonts. I also deleted a file called 00LOCK. Then I had an error that textshaping was missing. I installed that, restarted RStudio again and re-ran and it worked.